# Visual Studio 2010 WPF Designer scale

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, size

I made simple interface in Visual Studio 2010. When I launched application everything is bigger. Red square on screenshot represents size of the Button in launched application (On the right).
Am I missing something? How to fix it?

P.S.
In "Microsoft Expression Blend 4" the same project is exactly the same size as in editor.

---

[image: Windows][image: Scale Slider]

---

```
<Window x:Class="WpfControlReview.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="120" Width="256" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Label IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="Select your options and press to commit" Name="label1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" />
            <StackPanel Name="stackPanel2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Expander Header="Color" Name="expander1">
                </Expander>
                <Expander Header="Make" Name="expander2">
                </Expander>
                <Expander Header="Payment" Name="expander3">
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: some code would be very beneficial~~~

Comment: You must be using 64-bit machine right?

Comment: @Avatar Yes. Does it matter in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but the basic idea here is that you have specifed a default size for your window, but because the control wants to be bigger (for whatever reason) it will automatically resize the window. Could be a bug how Visual Studio calculates window border size in the designer with the specified parameters as it's incorrectly showing it as a bit smaller than when you actually launch your application.

I would rather suggest that you avoid specifying heights/widths if possible. Instead set the Window to SizeToContent=WidthAndHeight. If you need to play with the size of your controls use Margins or MinWidth/MinHeight set directly on your controls.

Comment: No. Wrong. In "Microsoft Expression Blend 4" the same project is exactly the same size as in editor.

Comment: Is the window in the Blends designer view bigger than it is in Visual Studio? Another thing, thw window shown in VS is exactly 120X256, but the real window is 130x266, so something is makeing it larger... If Blend also shows the window in the designer at 130x266 then that would explain what you are seeing. I don't believe that Blend and VS will compile different code, but the designer could easily show slightly different results...

Answer (score 1):

Are you zoomed out in the visual studio designer? Check the trackbar to your left and scroll it up and down to zoom in and out.

Comment: It is 100% (8 more character needed)

Answer (score 1):

Remeber that WPF scales the UI. Have you played with your DPI settings at all? This will affect the render of the UI componets on the display. Try running the app on a secondary machine to eleimate display issues.

**From MSDN:**

> Resolution-independent and
>   device-independent graphics. The basic
>   unit of measurement in the WPF
>   graphics system is the device
>   independent pixel, which is 1/96th of
>   an inch, regardless of actual screen
>   resolution, and provides the
>   foundation for resolution-independent
>   and device-independent rendering. Each
>   device-independent pixel automatically
>   scales to match the dots-per-inch
>   (dpi) setting of the system it renders
>   on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970268.aspx